# Post Data in Meteor router.go

Tags: meteor, router

How to send post data in meteor.go . I have tried parameters and query parameters to send the data but the data is displayed with the url .
Is there any way to send post data ?Currently i am using this
`Router.go('smsVerification', {mobile_no:options.mobile_no});

Comment: Iron Router component is not meant to do that thing. It is browser specific solution to manage url routing. If you want to send a url to server, then send it with $.post(); (i.e.) because with router.go it will not reach server as usually.

Comment: Is there any way to hide router.go parameters from the  url , i.e. if i am sending  '9111' as parameter then my url will become something like this  http://192.168.100.26:3000/smsVerification/9111 but i want it to be http://192.168.100.26:3000/smsVerification , Means the data should not be there in the url.

Comment: If you want to show data in the browser url then use Router, but if you don't want to do that then there is no sense to use it! Router.go is NOT a request, is browser client-routing. I'd suggest you to rethink whatever you want to and ask a question about it. But a question about the objective, not the problem you've got trying to solve it ;)

Comment: sorry for my mistake , i have mistakenly wrote 'post data' in my question , I just want to send a variable from client side routing . from router.go and using that variable from the target template via parameters  but url should not contain the parameter .Is there is any way to do this in meteor via iron routing

Comment: So you have a variable, a value, in a template and you want to use it in order template? If it is the case, I would suggest you to use Meteor Session feature. It is a local and temporal storage in the client side and it will not reset (I mean, the local store will remain) until you refresh completely the webpage. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: i have tried this before but as you said it will only remain until refreshing the page , the variable become undefined as i  refresh

Comment: Router is not the answer, because it will give you a normal url as the output (basically). If you want to store a value to be used somewhere in your application and it don't get lost, then you should store it by yourself (for example, using cookies).

Comment: However, I'd suggest you to rethink your problem because that does not seems to me to feet inside the normal meteor application workflow.

Comment: is there any way to store data which will remain persist even after refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to this is that you can't use Iron Router, the `Session` variable, or a client-only Collection to accomplish this. An easy -- but inelegant -- way around this is to persist the data to the server. You can add a handler to whatever button or link sends the user to that page to store the data you want to store -- probably directly to the `users` Collection -- then read that data back out on the page they're being linked to.  If you wanted to be really fancy about it you could add something that, when the user logs in or out, deletes this information.